# Error using struct defined in another file in UnitTesting (cppunit)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cppunit

I have a `Parser.h`, that defines a struct `StmtParent`:

```
...
struct StmtParent;

class Parser {
...
```

Then in `Parser.cpp`:

```
struct StmtParent {
    int stmtNo;
    int parent;
};
...
```

Seems all right? Then I have a unit test (cppunit):

```
# in ParserUnitTests.h
#include "header\Parser.h"

# in ParserUnitTests.cpp
void ParserUnitTests::testParseProcSideEffects() {
...
stack<StmtParent> follows;
    ...
```

Then I get errors like:

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'StmtParent'
```

Why, I can use functions like `Parser::parseLine()`. Why can't I access the struct? So I tried including `Parser.h` in `ParserUnitTests.cpp` (although I already have it included in the header). Then I get:

```
Error   8   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'm_cCurToken' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\parser.h    52
Error   9   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\parser.h    52
Error   10  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\parser.h    52
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Parser.h` does not define the struct, it forward-declares it. Therefore it's incomplete when you try to use it as a template parameter for the `stack`, and you can't use incomplete types as parameters for STL containers:

> C++11 draft 3035, 17.4.3.6, paragraph 2:
>
> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> ...
>
> > if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component,
> >     unless specifically allowed for that component.

You can check [this](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-standard-librarian-containers-of-inc/184403814) out for reasoning.

Comment: found that i need to define the struct in the header